# Using simple mapping object with angular ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm attempting to use a simple key: value mapping to define the elements of a select field but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for ng-options. What I have, currently looks like this:

```
this.selectOptions = {
    "Label One": "Value One",
    "Label Two": "Value Two"
};

<select
  ng-model="selectOption"
  ng-options="key for (key, value) selectOptions">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, forgot "in" in my selector.  Should have been:

```
<select
  ng-model="selectOption"
  ng-options="key for (key, value) in selectOptions">
</select>
```